# Existing text index into knn in opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

Hi I need to convert my old normal elastic search index into vector base index, i am using opensearch from aws for elastic search on my documents, i am storing the data in the form of text with basic metadata like

```
{
"c_id": 100,
"f_id" 102,
"text":"A vector search database, also known as a vector similarity search engine or vector database, is a type of database that is designed to store, retrieve, and search for vectors based on their similarity given a query. Vector search databases are frequently used in applications such as image retrieval, natural language processing, recommendation systems, and more.

Given the increasing excitement and interest in vector search and vector databases, we wanted to provide a high-level introduction of how it works and how it helps teams access information faster. In this post, we'll take a look at what vector search is and why you might use it, while walking you through some of the main types of vector databases and use cases.

Vector search differs from the previous generation of search engines because these databases represented data primarily using the text that they contain. They performed various processing steps on that text to improve the performance of search against that text, which included steps like preprocessing, query expansion, synonym lists, etc. These approaches aimed to address the challenges of words that have similar meanings and create an accurate representation of the intended meaning in a given text. The issue at hand is how to identify and compare two texts that express the same idea, but do not match exactly. For instance, if a user searches for "tree," but a text uses the term "plant.""
}
```

in above u see i am dumping all the data in the normal text field , now i need to run the RAG(Retrival) for Question answering from AWS Bedrock. i am design my own costume retrival using elastic MLT query but return me all the text of document because i am dumping in one document that's the bad approach.

As per my understanding of this problem i need to convert all old index data into vector base, there is any way to automate or transform text to vector

Comment: Please check if this article helps: https://opster.com/guides/opensearch/opensearch-machine-learning/how-to-set-up-vector-search-in-opensearch/ you should find what you need with the Neural Search plugin